# Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a method that accepts a String argument parameter, searches a file for that word and returns a count of the occurrences of that word. I am using Java Regex Pattern and Matcher classes and methods. The way that I have implemented Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE does not seem to function correctly. It is still matching on a case sensitive basis.

```
public int lookup(String wrd) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, 
{  
    int cnt = 0;     

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.filename));

    String line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    { 
        Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile(wrd, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher mtch = ptn.mtch(line);
        if (mtch.find()) {cnt++;}
        line = input.readLine();
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample input data? Both the pattern and a (small) part of the file that's being read from?

Comment: You have a bunch of weird mistakes in your code. What is `input` here  `line = input.readLine();`. What is this method `ptn.mtch(line);`, `java.util.regex.Pattern` has `matcher` method. If you want all occurrences of the word then you should do `while (mtch.find())` instead of  `if (mtch.find())`... Just fix it and probably it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like I mentioned in the comment fix the mistakes. Here is a bit modified and fixed version of your code. This way seems like everything works:

```
  public static int lookup(String wrd) throws IOException {
    int cnt = 0;

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new StringReader(new String("word adfasdword avcasf\n asdf WoRd asdfWORDasdf")));

    String line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
      Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile(wrd, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
      Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher(line);
      while (mtch.find()) {
        cnt++;
      }
      line = in.readLine();
    }
    return cnt;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(lookup("WORD"));
    System.out.println(lookup("word"));
    System.out.println(lookup("WorD"));
    System.out.println(lookup("worLd"));
  }
```

Output:

```
4
4
4
0
```

Comment: Thank you - the "While (mtch.find())" was the key issue in my code. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not scrolling through the lines in the file and only reading first line. There is no reason to use regex, for most languages you can combine `toLowerCase()` with `indexOf()` to get a case insensitive position check.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Path p = ...
  String wrd = ...
  System.out.println(totalMatches(p, wrd));
}

private static int totalMatches(Path path, String word) throws IOException {
  try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
    return reader.lines()
        .mapToInt(l -> lineMatches(l, word))
        .sum();
  }
}

private static int lineMatches(String line, String word) {
  int counter = 0, i = 0, found;
  while ((found = line.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase(), i)) >= 0) {
    counter++;
    i = found + 1;
  }
  return counter;
}
```